# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING with index.php?

Tags: php, indexing

It works perfectly in local host but when I upload it intothe server it has the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\Hosting\4923367\html\beta\index.php on line 4
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'localization.php';
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--Start Kampyle Exit-Popup Code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var k_push_vars = {
    "view_percentage": 10,
    "popup_font_color": "#000000",
    "popup_background": "#D4E2F0",
    "header": "Your feedback is important to us!",
    "question": "Would you be willing to give us a short (1 minute) feedback?",
    "footer": "Thank you for helping us improve our website",
    "yes": "Yes",
    "no": "No",
    "text_direction": "ltr",
    "images_dir": "http://cf.kampyle.com/",
    "yes_background": "#76AC78",
    "no_background": "#8D9B86",
    "site_code": 9662374
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cf.kampyle.com/k_push.js"></script>
<!--End Kampyle Exit-Popup Code-->

<!-- Start Kampyle Css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cf.kampyle.com/k_button.css" />
<!-- End Kampyle Css -->
```

(continues)

Comment: unless you are serving this with an application/xhtml+xml you don't need the prolog. And if you do, you should be aware of http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#ie

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<?xml` is being mistaken for PHP short-tag, try echoing it ( although I don't see a need for it )

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be conflicting settings in the php.ini files on your respective servers.  Try editing the `php.ini` file on your server and set

```
short_open_tag = 0
```

More information about the directives available in your `php.ini` file can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: This is the real solution, not encoding <?xml

Comment: or you could write:
`echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';`

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
<?php
include_once 'localization.php';
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

with this:

```
<?php
include_once 'localization.php';
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access only to nginx site configuration, just add following string to your site config file (in section for php):

> fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE short_open_tag=0;

And restart nginx.